# Showing that $I_aJ \subseteq I$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $I$ be an ideal in an integral domain $R$, and define the ideals $I_a = (I, a)$ where $a \in R-I$, and $J = \{r \in R: rI_a \subseteq I\}$. It is also known that $I_a$ and $J$ are principal ideals, so $I_a = (\alpha)$ and $J = (\beta)$. We then have $I_aJ = (\alpha\beta)$. To show set containment, we let $x \in I_aJ$ be arbitrary.

Then we can write $x = r(\alpha\beta)$ for $r \in R$. Then since $\alpha \in I_a$, we can write $\alpha = qs + at$, where $q \in I$ and $s,t \in R$. So then $x = r(qs+at)\beta$. It's at this point that I am stuck. I know that since $\beta \in J$, we have $x \in J$ by properties of ideals. This would imply that $xI_a \subseteq I$, but that doesn't seem to imply that $x \in I$. Can someone help?

Comment: Is your title correct? You seem to be trying to prove $I_a J \subseteq I$, rather than $I_a J \subseteq J$ in the second paragraph.

Comment: I fixed it, thank you!

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something, but isn't it just follow from the definition of $J$?

Comment: That is an important part of it, but I'm trying to show it more rigorously with a set containment argument.

Comment: I think Zhang's suggestion is quite rigorous. Remember that $I_a J$ is the smallest ideal containing $xy$ for all $x \in I_a$ and $y \in J$. Can you show those all belong to $I$? (It's not totally clear to me why $I_a$ and $J$ must be principal ideals, by the way. Can't you have $I_a = (2, x)$ in $\Bbb Z[x]$?)

Comment: In the specific realm of the problem, these ideals are principal (which matters for something I proved later on). But to be honest, I don't see how $xy \in I$. If $x=a$ for instance, since $a \in R-I$, all we can say is that $xy \in J$, right?

Answer (score 0):

Since $x=r(qs+at)\beta$, with $r,s,t \in R$, $q \in I$, and $\beta \in J$, we can distribute out the terms to get that $x = q(rs\beta) + \beta a(rt)$. The first term is in $I$ since $q \in I$ and ideals absorb products. The second term contains $\beta a \in I_aJ$. Since $\beta \in J$, we have that $\beta I_a \subseteq I$ by the definition of $J$.

But then since $\beta a \in \beta I_a$, this implies that $\beta a \in I$, and so by properties of ideals, $\beta a(rt) \in I$, and since both terms are in $I$, their sum $x \in I$.